# Send Dropdownlist select item to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got this in a View:

```
<form method="post" action="../MasterData/SaveRoad">
...
<input type="text" name="description" maxlength="100">
@Html.DropDownList("concessions")
...
```

And in a controller, this:

```
public ActionResult SaveRoad()
{
    string description = Request["description"].ToString();
    // code to get the dropdownlist selected value??
...
```

Now, I'm getting the description using the `Request` but how can I get the selected value of the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `Request["description"]` is somewhat against the nature of ASP.NET MVC. Please don't. Rather declare this and the other input you have (dropdown) as parameters of the action:

```
public ActionResult SaveRoad(string description, string concessions)
```

Comment: Man, I didn't know that the action of the form would take as parameters the inputs it contains and that to access them you'd only need to write their names in the parameters of the `ActionResult`. I've been using `Request` all over. Thanks